# How to find out where the Github action was triggered

Tags: github-actions

I would expect for each triggered GitHub action, to be able to find it and understand what triggered it.

To be concrete, we have a `changelog.yml`file:

```yaml
name: Changelog Updater

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
    paths:
      - 'pyproject.toml' # When somebody update the toml file

jobs:
  build:
    name: Update changelog
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Generate changelog
        uses: orhun/git-cliff-action@v1
        with:
          config: .github/workflows/cliff.toml
        env:
          OUTPUT: CHANGELOG.md
      - name: Commit changelog
        uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v4
        with:
          commit_message: "chore(changelog): update changelog to newest version"
          file_pattern: CHANGELOG.md
```

That should be triggered when a push on `master` with a change on `pyproject.toml` occur.

But in some PR, like https://github.com/eclipse/kiso-testing/pull/185/commits, we see that the `action` is triggered because `github_action[bot]` committed something:

[image]

But I cannot find where it is...

[image]

I would expect here to find the `workflow` regarding the above triggered PR but it is simply not there.

I did try to check all forks or the checks of all PRs but I do not find what triggered or the location of this specific `action`. Some other PRs are not impacted. It feels strange.

Comment: Your implementation would trigger for 2 different events: 1. when pushing to `main` branch. 2. when pushing a commit which update the `pyproject.toml` file on any branch. The workflow trigger setup is an OR condition, not an AND condition.

Comment: Ok, I must have miss-read the documentation then...
What confuse me is that it is not always the case, e.g. https://github.com/eclipse/kiso-testing/pull/184/commits does not trigger any... It is somehow not predictable :-/

I somehow have 8 PRs currently pointing to master but none of them triggered the commit.
If I assume you are right, why can't I see the `action` being triggered?

Comment: In the example you shared above, the workflow didn't trigger because the push was made from a forked repository (in that case, it doesn't trigger automatically without extra configuration in the upstream repo).

Comment: So it means, for https://github.com/eclipse/kiso-testing/pull/185/commits, the contributor configured something on his side / fork?

Comment: Yes, someone probably approved the workflow run for this PR. [Check this reference to understand more about this behavior](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/approving-workflow-runs-from-public-forks).

Comment: We found the issue thanks to you: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository#configuring-the-default-github_token-permissions (4)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248905/discussion-between-sebastianpfischer-and-guifalourd).